# Proof explanation: finding the coefficient of $(r+1)$th term in the expansion of $\left(1-6x\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$?

Tags: proof-explanation, binomial-coefficients

Here is the answer of the math..

$\displaystyle\left(1-6x\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

$\displaystyle=\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}-1\right)....\left(-\frac{1}{2}-r+1_{ }\right)}{r!}\left(-6x\right)^r$

$\displaystyle=\frac{\left(-1\right)^r\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}+1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}+2\right)....\left(r-1+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{r!}\left(-1\right)^r.\:x^r.\:2^r.3^r$

$\displaystyle=\left(-1\right)^{2r}\:\frac{1.3.5.7.....\left(2r-1\right)}{2^r\:.\:r!}\:\:x^r.\:2^r.3^r$

$\displaystyle=\frac{\left\{1.3.5.7.....\left(2r-1\right)\right\}\left(2.4.6....2r\right)}{r!\:\left(2.4.6.....2r\right)}\:\:x^r.\:3^r$

$\displaystyle=\frac{1.2.3.4.....2r}{r!\:2^r\:\left(1.2.3.\:....r\right)}\:\:x^r.\:3^r$

$\displaystyle=\frac{\left(2r\right)!\:\:.\:3^r}{2^r\:.\:\left(r!\right)^2}\:\:x^r$

$\displaystyle=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^r\:\frac{\left(2r\right)!\:}{\:\left(r!\right)^2}\:.\:\:x^r$

I can't understand the 4th and 6th line of this math . Please explain me that lines..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^r\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}+1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}+2\right)\cdots\left(r-1+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{r!}\left(-1\right)^rx^r2^r3^r}\\
> &\qquad=\frac{\left(-1\right)^r\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1+2}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1+4}{2}\right)\cdots\left(\frac{2r-2+1}{2}\right)}{r!}\left(-1\right)^rx^r2^r3^r\tag{1}\\
> &\qquad=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{2r}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)\cdots\left(\frac{2r-1}{2}\right)}{r!}x^r2^r3^r\tag{2}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{=(-1)^{2r}\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2r-1)}{2^rr!}x^r2^r3^r}\tag{3}\\
> &\qquad=\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2r-1)\cdot  2\cdot   4\cdot  6\cdots  (2r)}{r!2\cdot   4\cdot  6\cdots  (2r)}x^r3^r\tag{4}\\
> &\qquad=\frac{(2r)!}{r!(2\cdot1)\cdot   (2\cdot 2)\cdot  (2\cdot 3)\cdots  (2r)}x^r3^r\tag{5}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{=\frac{(2r)!}{r!2^r1\cdot   2\cdot 3\cdots  r}x^r3^r}\tag{6}\\
> \end{align*}

*Common:*

- In (1) we use a common denominator $2$ for the factors in the numerator.
- In (2) we do a simplification and collect the factors $(-1)^r$.
- In (3) we observe there are $r$ factors $\frac{1}{2}$  which can be written as $2^r$ in the denominator.
- In (4) we see odd factors $1,3,5,\ldots,2r-1$ in the numerator. Since we wish to use the more compact notation of *factorials* we expand numerator and denominator with corresponding even factors. We also use that an even number of factors $(-1)$ give $1$.
- In (5) we write the numerator using factorial notation and observe that each even factor in the denominator can be written a $2\cdot k$.
- In (6) we factor out $r$ factors $2$ giving $2^r$.

Answer (score 0):

In line 4, $(n+1/2) = (2n+1)/2$ for all n running from 0 to r-1 and in denominator there become 2's r times which give $2^r$ in denominator. In next line they have multiplied $1.2...r$ and they distribute 2's for each n  running from 1 to r which becomes $2.4....2r$ ($2^r$ is in numerator too). In next line they take back 2's which becomes $2^r$ in denominator and in numerator they rearrange each term which become $(2r)!$.